# Why is a number of shares that is greater than a threshold required to construct a secret?

Tags: secret-sharing, number-theory

In [this](http://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/440d/fa8ab99301d4ea3a8b19c0748575915aef15.pdf) paper of **Asmuth–Bloom threshold SSS**, the algorithm is as follows:

**Shares Distribution**

To distribute n shares of a secret $K$ among the set of participants
$P = \{ p_i : 1 ≤ i ≤ n\}$, the dealer D does the following:

1. A set of integers $\{ p, m_1 < m_2 < · · · < m_n \}$, where $0 ≤ K < p$, is chosen subject to the following conditions:

$$\gcd(m_i , m_j)=1 \text{ where for } i\neq j$$
$$\gcd(p , m_i)=1,\text{ for all } i$$
$$\prod \limits_{i=1}^{t}m_i > p \prod \limits_{i=1}^{t-1}m_{n-i+1}$$

2. Let $M =\prod \limits_{i=1}^{t}m_i$. The dealer computes $$y = K+ap,$$
   where a is a positive integer generated randomly subject to the condition that $0 ≤ y < M$
3. The share of the $i^{th}$ participant,$1 ≤ i ≤ n$, is $$y_i = y~ mod ~m_i$$

**Secret  Construction**

Assume $C$ is a coalition of $t$ participants to construct the secret.
Let $M_C =\prod \limits_{i=1}^{C}m_i$

1. Given the system $$y \equiv y_ i \mod m_ i $$  for $i ∈ C$, solve y in $GF(M_C  )$ uniquely using the CRT.
2. Compute the secret as
   $$K = y \mod p$$

According to the CRT, y can be determined uniquely in $GF(M_ C)$ . Since $y < M ≤ M_C$ , the solution is also unique in $GF(M)$.

In [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1056651) original paper the author given to  recover $K$ , it clearly suffices to find y. If $y_{1},y_{2}.......y_{t}$ are known, then by the Chinese remainder theorem modulo $M_C =\prod \limits_{i=1}^{C}m_i$ .
As  $M ≤ M_C$ this uniquely determines $y$ and thus $K$ . On the other
hand, if   only $t-1$ shares were known, essentially no information about  the secret can be recovered

---

*How to prove formally that the number of participants **lesser than threshold number $t$** cannot get secret?*

Comment: It is not $GF(M_C)$ but the integers modulo $M_C$  you operate over.

Answer (score 4):

To show that the adversary could not retrieve the secret, you can show that two different secrets will implies the same shares, and then an adversary that has access to these shares could not retrieve the secret.

To show that the adversary has no bit of information about the secret when he has $t'$ strictly less than $t$ shares, you can show that if you take two different $K_1$ and $K_2$, and compute the cardinality of $a$'s (for $k_1$ and for $K_2$) such that you obtain the $t'$ shares. Because they are the same, and because $a$ is uniformly picked at random, you deduce the perfect secrecy.
First I'm claiming that $a$ is chosen unifromly at random in $\{0, \dots, M-1 \}$ (I can give you more details, if you aren't not convinced.
Let $\left(y_1, \dots, y_{n-1}\right)$ a vector of shares.\newline
We call $\psi$ the isomorphism given by the chinese remainder theorem from $\mathbb{Z}_{m_1} \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_{m_n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{Mp}$, and $\phi$ the invert isomorphism.

$$Card \{a \in \{0, \dots, M-1 \} / \exists \left(z, z'\right) \in  \mathbb{Z}_{m_n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p}, \phi \left(K_1 + a*p\right) = \left(y_1, \dots, y_{n-1}, z, z'\right)\}$$

$$ = Card \{a \in \{0, \dots, M-1 \} / \exists \left(z, z'\right) \in  \mathbb{Z}_{m_n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p}, \phi \left(K_1\right) + \phi\left(a\right)*\phi\left(p\right) = \left(y_1, \dots, y_{n-1}, z, z'\right) \}$$

$$ = Card \{a \in \{0, \dots, M-1 \} / \exists \left(z, z'\right) \in  \mathbb{Z}_{m_n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p},  \phi\left(a\right)*\phi\left(p\right) = \left(y_1 - \left(K_1 \mod m_{1} \right), \dots, y_{n-1} - \left(K_1 \mod m_{n-1}\right), z - \left(K_1 \mod m_{n}\right), z' - \left(K_1 \mod p\right) \right) \}$$

Because $p \mod p = 0$, we deduce, that necessarily  $z' = K_1 \mod p$ (and such $z'$ exists).

$$ = Card \{a \in \{0, \dots, M-1 \} / \exists z \in  \mathbb{Z}_{m_n},  \phi\left(a\right) = \left(\frac{y_1 - \left(K_1 \mod m_{1} \right)}{p \mod m_{n-1}}, \dots, \frac{y_{n-1} - \left(K_1 \mod m_{n-1}\right)}{p \mod m_{n-1}}, \frac{\left(z - \left(K_1 \mod m_{n}\right)\right)}{p \mod m_n}, 0\right) \}$$

$$ = Card \{a \in \{0, \dots, M-1 \} / \exists z \in  \mathbb{Z}_{m_n},  a = \psi\left(\frac{y_1 - \left(K_1 \mod m_{1} \right)}{p \mod m_{n-1}}, \dots, \frac{y_{n-1} - \left(K_1 \mod m_{n-1}\right)}{p \mod m_{n-1}}, \frac{\left(z - \left(K_1 \mod m_{n}\right)\right)}{p \mod m_n}, 0\right) \}$$.

This cardinal doesn't depend of $K_1$ (it's equal to $m_n$).

Comment: While the method you describe can (presumably; I haven't actually done it myself) be used to show that less than $t$ shares are not (always) sufficient to *definitively and unambiguously* reconstruct the secret, it doesn't prove that an attacker with less than $t$ shares cannot learn *anything* about the secret. For that, you'd need a slightly more complex argument.

Comment: Sorry I didn't well understood the question, I edit my post right now

Comment: please tell me what is cardinality you are referred here

Comment: Could I suppose all the m_i's are prime numbers? Could you precise exactly and properly in which set $a$ is picked?

Comment: The m_i's can be prime numbers. where a is a positive integer generated randomly subject to the condition that 0≤y<M

Comment: I edit my answer, with more details, tell me if it's enough.

Comment: I have multiple examples where in a 3 out of 4 scheme, 2 shares are enough to reconstruct the secret. Even with your proof, to me it is completely unclear why 2 shares would never leak any information about the secret, while for me it is possible to retrieve the secret from less than $t$ shares, using multiple implementations of asmuth-bloom or just pen and paper.

Comment: Because, you can't retrieve the $y$ (because the $m_i$ are coprime)

Comment: $a$ value is not in the range $\{0......(M-1)\}$,  $a$  value should be in the range $a=\{0....\frac{M−1}{2}\}$,  your  proof  is  based on $a$ cardinality . Could you please check once your proof.

Comment: When I read your first post, I see that $a$ is in the range $\{0...(M-1)\}$